# Attempting to use tapply in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I would like to avoid running long bits of code in Spotfire and avoid using the OVER functions. I am attempting to calculate the means of total $ amounts per category (in this case the categories are AMEX, Visa, etc).

I ran the R script in Spotfire and didn't get any errors. It looks like this:

```
output <- tapply(input1, input2, input3)
```

I specified output and all inputs to be column except input3 since this is a string with the name of the desired function to be applied (such as "mean" or "sd").

However, when I attempt to insert a calculated column in Spotfire to generate the means per category like so

```
"TERR_Real("output <- tapply(input1,input2,input3", [TenderTotal], [TenderName], "mean")"
```

I get the following error :

> "TIBCO Enterprise Runtime for R returned an error: 'Error in
>   parse(text = script) : parse error in text argument: unexpected end of
>   input before closing ')''.    at
>   Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFunctions.Executors.LocalFunctionClient.OnExecuting(FunctionClient
>   funcClient)    at
>   Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFunctions.Executors.AbstractFunctionClient.d__0.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFunctions.Executors.SPlusFunctionExecutor.d__0.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Methods.TerrMethod`1.CalculateColumnCore(ColumnBuilder`1
>   columnBuilder, Int32 rowCount, IList`1 arguments)

Comment: Why avoid a native Spotfire function for one that requires an additional run-time environment to support a language that hogs memory... all for a simple calculation? It seems like you are building a race car only to drive 1 mile each day. Kind of an overkill.

Comment: That's a great point. I am just starting to work in Spotfire however so I tend to automatically lean more toward using R in tandem with Spotfire.

Comment: R is definitely powerful, but your analysis will be faster and easier maintained if you learn some of the internal functions. While I have only used R for a few specific reasons and am of no help here, let me know if you want help transforming this to an internal logic.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but maybe you didn't close your tapply function?

```
TERR_Real("output <- tapply(input1,input2,input3)", [TenderTotal], [TenderName], "mean")
```